# Python index usage

Tags: python, indexing

Here is some code:
    # Question 9: Deep Reverse
    # Define a procedure, deep_reverse, that takes as input a list, 
    # and returns a new list that is the deep reverse of the input list.
    # This means it reverses all the elements in the list, and if any 
    # of those elements are lists themselves, reverses all the elements 
    # in the inner list, all the way down.

```
# Note: The procedure must not change the input list.

# The procedure is_list below is from Homework 6. It returns True if 
# p is a list and False if it is not.

def is_list(p):
    return isinstance(p, list)

#For example,
def deep_reverse(n):
    n.reverse()
    for entry in n:
        if is_list(entry):
            entry.reverse() 
            deep_reverseA(entry)        
    return n

def deep_reverseA(n):
    for entry in n:
        if is_list(entry):
            entry.reverse() 
            deep_reverseA(entry)          
    return n

p = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6]]]]
print deep_reverse(p)
#>>> [[[[6, 5], 4], 3, 2], 1]
print p
#>>> [1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6]]]]

q =  [1, [2,3], 4, [5,6]]
print deep_reverse(q)
#>>> [ [6,5], 4, [3, 2], 1]
print q
#>>> [1, [2,3], 4, [5,6]]
```

My problem is that once I run the code the values of p and q change. How can I make them not change. I know that in python indexes are connected so if indexA = indexB and you change indexA then indexB will change. That is the problem I am having with fixing this problem.

Comment: This seems like a homework problem.  If I just give you the answer, I've done nothing to help you.  Read through some documentation, I am sure you will be able to solve this on your own.

Comment: You might want to think of what you want to do with it. You don't want the original list, but you want a `...` of it. Try searching for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just tell you the answer right here, right now, with an explanation.

In python, variables are merely **pointers** to stored objects. So as you said in your post, if you declare `foo = bar` then `foo` not only is equal to `bar`, but `foo` **is** `bar`. This won't change unless you explicitly say so (for example you set `bar = 2`). So you need a way to make a **copy** of the original list.

There's this thing in python called *list slicing*, and I'm sure you heard of it. Basically you can get a portion of the list from `indexA` to `indexB` with `my_list[indexA:indexB]`.

But  you can also leave these spaces blank. `indexA` if not specified defaults to `0`, and `indexB` defaults to `-1` (the last element of the list).

So `my_list[2:]` returns all the elements from `my_list[2]` to `my_list[-1]`. Likewise, `my_list[:3]` returns `my_list[0]` to `my_list[3]`.

Therefore, calling `my_list[:]` returns an **exact copy** of `my_list`, but not the actual list itself. This is what you need to do.

So applying it to your code:

```
def deep_reverse(n):
    ncopy = n[:]  #this is the part you need
    #rest of function, replace `n` with `ncopy`
    return ncopy
```

Also, **do not** apply this to `deep_reverseA` because in that function you are changing the **original** list in the **copied** list. You aren't changing the list you input into `deep_reverse`. If you did apply this to `deep_reverseA`, the lists wouldn't actually change (you would be returning a reverse of the *copy* but not the original)

Comment: Thank a lot. It was odd though because I used copy = n[:] and it didn't work. So I found something where I can import copy and ncopy = copy.deepcopy(n).

Comment: That's really odd... but good to know you figured something out.